# ios swift crop image to the size of device

Tags: ios, swift, background-image, crop

everyone. For the App on which I am working I want to let users be able to select own image and set it as the background of App. The Problem I face is how to let users crop the image fitting the size of device's screen if the image is larger. Another question is if users want to select a pretty small image and set it as the background, should I just say no to it?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how you've set up your app so we can only speculate. BUT you could create a UIImageView that is behind everything else. When the user selects a picture just set that picture to that image views background....

As for the cropping...if you use constraints and tell that image view to be 0 from top, 0 from left, 0 from right, and 0 from bottom it will automatically resize based on size of device. Also you would need to set that image views scale property so the image doesn't distort...

Finally, usually when you have images on the device you create a 1x, 2x, and 3x size and Xcode will automatically use the appropriate size ...but again we have no idea how your app works...so if the user is trying to use an image that is 15 pixels by 15 pixels and have it fill the whole screen...it's going to look pixelated

You might want to write a function that gets the image size and if it fails to meet specifications you set...tell the user somehow (UIAlert...)

All of that being said...

Folk here on Stack Overflow generally don't take time to help on questions that have no code example shown...generally speaking you attempt to figure it out first and then post...so show code that you've tried, or take a screen shot of how your View Controller looks like...